# VisibleDeprecationWarning in python

Tags: python, numpy

I am new to Python and have been trying to find out bag of words. I used vectorizer.fit_transform function as follows

```
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(vocabulary=set_of_words, tokenizer=nltk.word_tokenize)
bag_of_words = vectorizer.fit_transform(doc).toarray().astype(np.float64)
```

where doc contains the text whose bag of words is to be extracted.

and i get a warning as follows:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py:2499: here`VisibleDeprecationWarning:`rank`is deprecated; use the`ndim`attribute or function instead. To find the rank of a matrix see`numpy.linalg.matrix_rank`.
  VisibleDeprecationWarning)

On displaying vectorizer I get something like this

```
CountVectorizer(analyzer=u'word', binary=False, charset=None,
    charset_error=None, decode_error=u'strict',
    dtype=<type 'numpy.int64'>, encoding=u'utf-8', input=u'content',
    lowercase=True, max_df=1.0, max_features=None, min_df=1,
    ngram_range=(1, 1), preprocessor=None, stop_words=None,
    strip_accents=None, token_pattern=u'(?u)\\b\\w\\w+\\b',
    tokenizer=<function word_tokenize at 0xafbc6f4>,
    vocabulary=[u'dissolution', u'comparatively', u'desirable', u'four', u'obstruction', u'nursery', u'perverted', u'appetite', u'repress', u'consider'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using Scipy / Scite and hitting this bug https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/3866 ?

Comment: es I tried to incorporate changes in the files of scipy as mentioed in the link provided above.

But now what i get is

ImportError: cannot import name __check_build

Answer (score 3):

From TessellatingHeckler's link I found out: "It's one of those scipy calling old numpy function things"

Running `pip install --upgrade scipy` resolved this issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

The issue has been resolved.. The modifications mentioned in 
https://github.com/scipy/scipy/commit/fa1782e04fdab91f672ccf7a4ebfb887de50f01c
when made in the scipy files solved the problem.