# run time warning in asfortranarray

Tags: python, numpy

I am working on `Dictionary Learning` by using `SPAMS` in `Python`.

Here is my code =>

```
import spams
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img_file = 'gray-car.jpg'
try:
    img = Image.open(img_file)
except:
    print("Cannot load image %s : skipping test" %img_file)
I = np.array(img) / 255.

print('Shape : ',I.shape)

if I.ndim == 3:
    A = np.asfortranarray(I.reshape((I.shape[0],I.shape[1] * I.shape[2])))
    rgb = True
else:
    A = np.asfortranarray(I)
    rgb = False

m = 8;n = 8;
X = spams.im2col_sliding(A,m,n,rgb)

X = X - np.tile(np.mean(X,0),(X.shape[0],1))
X = np.asfortranarray(X / np.tile(np.sqrt((X * X).sum(axis=0)),(X.shape[0],1)),dtype=np.float64)
param = { 'K' : 100, # learns a dictionary with 100 elements
          'lambda1' : 0.15, 'numThreads' : 4, 'batchsize' : 400,
          'iter' : 1000}

tic = time.time()
D = spams.trainDL(X,**param)
tac = time.time()
t = tac - tic
print('time of computation for Dictionary Learning: %f' %t)

##param['approx'] = 0
# save dictionnary as dict.png
plt.imshow(D)
plt.show()
_objective(X,D,param,'dict')
```

Here the error that I am getting during learning =>

```
noise.py:27: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide 
X = np.asfortranarray(X / np.tile(np.sqrt((X *
X).sum(axis=0)),(X.shape[0],1)),dtype=np.float64)
/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py:2699:
VisibleDeprecationWarning: `rank` is deprecated; use the `ndim`
attribute or function instead. To find the rank of a matrix see
`numpy.linalg.matrix_rank`.   VisibleDeprecationWarning)
```

Input Image that I have used here =>

[image]

Comment: I think you have a zero (or nan/inf) in the divisor. I don't think this has anything to do with `np.asfortranarray`. Please also share some sample input so we can _actually_ verify the code.

Comment: @MSeifert I am uploading the pic that i Have used there

Comment: Tell us about the expression inside the `asfortran`, `X / np.tile(np.sqrt((X * X).sum(axis=0))`.  shape, dtype, whether it runs, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's guess the `X` somehow represents an image, and has a 'white' border:

```
In [127]: X=np.zeros((10,10))
In [128]: X[3:8,3:8]=1
 ....
In [130]: np.sqrt(X*X).sum(axis=0)
Out[130]: array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  5.,  5.,  5.,  5.,  5.,  0.,  0.])
```

The tiled division could easily contain 0s, and produce the runtime warning:

```
In [134]: X/np.tile(np.sqrt((X * X).sum(axis=0)),(X.shape[0],1))
/usr/local/bin/ipython3:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
  #!/usr/bin/python3
Out[134]: 
array([[       nan,        nan,        nan,  0.       ,  0.       ,
         0.       ,  0.       ,  0.       ,        nan,        nan],
       [       nan,        nan,        nan,  0.       ,  0.       ,
         0.       ,  0.       ,  0.       ,        nan,        nan],
            ...     ,
         0.       ,  0.       ,  0.       ,        nan,        nan]])
```

I don't know why it's using `asfortranarray()`, but I don't get any further errors from that.

[VisibleDeprecationWarning in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27182244/visibledeprecationwarning-in-python)

is an example of posts asking about this `VisibleDeprecationWarning`.  Theres is a `np.rank` function:

```
In [138]: np.rank(X)
/usr/local/bin/ipython3:1: VisibleDeprecationWarning: `rank` is deprecated; use the `ndim` attribute or function instead. To find the rank of a matrix see `numpy.linalg.matrix_rank`.
  #!/usr/bin/python3
```

Some old or obscure piece of code is using `rank` instead of `ndim`.

I'm tempted to blame `asfortranarray`, which I haven't seen used before.  But its current code is only:

```
return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order='F', ndmin=1)
```

which shouldn't have obscure corners hiding a `rank` call.

I think we need to know more about `X`, esp it's shape and dtype.  Maybe also its strides.  `im2col_sliding` suggests it's a sliding window array generated with `as_strided`.